# Python Spyder console hanging

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

anaconda python spyder console is hanging. ran previous projects where i imported web browser, requests, selenium and it seems so have materially slowed down post running these associated imports. how get the console back up the speed observed prior to using these imports. have tried to reset settings but had no luck.

FYI - i am running windows 10

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Without seeing a simple and reproducible code example that slow downs our console, it's not possible for us to help you, sorry.

Comment: for example from print('hello world') it takes 5seconds to show hello world on the console